# preg_match with PHP 8.2 update not working

Tags: php, error-handling, deprecated

Hi i am currently getting the following error after upgrading PHP to 8.2.6

PHP Deprecated

this is my code

```
public function __toString() {
    return (
        preg_match('/^\^/',$this->_pageTitle))?str_replace('^','',$this->_pageTitle):$this->view->escape($this->_pageTitle);
}
```